# How to disable template feature in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking forward to use Symfony2. But i dont want to use a template engine. How can I disable the default templating engine "twig" and use native php?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

This page explains how to use plain php instead of twig. Also to remove twig capability from your app you can also remove it from the config file

```
framework:
    # ...
    templating:    { engines: ['php'] }
```

Comment: If you don't want even to have the twig bundle at all, because you want just to use symfony to create a standalone php command line console command, then you can also get rid of twig by edition composer.json, removing it from AppKernel, and removing twig and removing all the section in parameters.yml. But then what? you need to remove it from "templating.engines" but it cannot be [] because the system complains that templating must have at least 1 element. Setting engines:['php'] removes dependencies to nearly zero.